# Where to implement garbage collection in a Dockerized FastAPI application?

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a dockerized Python code that exposes some APIs via Swagger docs using FastAPI.  This software allows me to schedule tasks that run every 10 minutes indefinitely until I delete the task.

After running the application for 20-30 days, it gets exceptionally slow (going from 9 seconds to over 5 minutes per execution). I believe there's some memory leak occurring and want to implement garbage collection.

However, I am not sure where to put garbage collection.  Would I write `import gc` and `gc.enable()` in my FastAPI `main.py` file where all my APIs are?  Or would I have to `import gc` in each Python module?

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection is enabled by default, so running `gc.enable()` or `gc.collect()` will not change anything.

Comment: Is there documentation or anything surrounding this

Comment: Read about garbage collection in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)
It is not for dealing with memory leaks. In that case you can use memory profiler to check which data is more and more.